# Keep link a:active the same way after link press

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, onclick

I was playing around with css and html today, and I was trying to get an image/link to change its form when being hovered over and clicked. But what I did not manage to do was for the image that I picked to stay "clicked" when I click the image.

Here is the CSS:

```
#header {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
#logo a {
    background-image:url(logo.png);
    display:block;
    width:128px;
    height:32px;
}
#logo a:hover {
    background-image:url(logohover.png);
    display:block;
    width:128px;
    height:32px;
}
#logo a:focus {
    background-image:url(logoonclick.png);
    display:block;
    width:128px;
    height:32px;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want the link or image to stay in the form "clicked" after being clicked, and if clicked again I want it to change back to its standard from.

Comment: There is no onclick handler with html or css. This can be achieved by using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use Javascript to toggle a class on the link, then add the class to the a:hover's CSS.

In jQuery, this would look something like:

```
$('#logo a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Then change the CSS to add the new class:

```
#logo a:hover, .clicked {
    /* ... */
}
```

If you don't want to use Javascript, you could also style the `a:visited` to look like the hover state - when clicked, the link would look like it was still clicked. However, you won't be able to change it back to the pre-clicked state using only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your a-element with a input[type=checkbox] and a label you can get something like you want with the :checked-pseudeselector:

http://jsfiddle.net/CWv6D/

```
#foo {
    display: none;
}
#logo label {
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/128x32);
    display:block;
    width:128px;
    height:32px;
}
#logo label:hover {
    background-image:url(http://placesheen.com/128/32);
}
#logo input:checked + label {
    background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/128/32);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <input id="foo" type="checkbox"/>
      <label for="foo"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `placesheen` is my new default placeholder.  Sorry `placekitten` (and `placedog`).

Comment: Thanks, but will this make the image a link though?

Comment: @Awat Langø: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want this to be a link, why would you want for it to display a different picture after it was clicked?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is what I want to achieve; I want it to display a list under the image after being clicked, so I want the image to be active while the list is displaying.

Comment: Do you use Javascript to display the list?

Comment: No, I don't. But I would be accepting any tips, but please do with some in-depth style though.

Comment: It works the same as with the label. I don't know how to explain that technique in more detail.